# How can I use .fsx script file in my project?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, f#

I'm using F#. I made a script file, inside my project folder, called script.fsx, and it just has `open System.IO` as its only line. What do I have to do in order to get my project to use this script, so that the namespace is automatically included?

Comment: Your question is not answerable in this form. Please describe what effect you want to achieve and what you have tried so far.

Comment: fsx files are not compiled. You can reference them with the `#load` directive from other files.

Comment: I realized, right after I left, my question was bad and it's not possible to achieve what I wanted. I misunderstood how fsx files work when trying to understand them.